# Error while building Docker image for Druid

Tags: docker, hadoop, curl, druid

I am doing this [tutorial](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-batch-hadoop.html) to load batch data using Apache Hadoop and I try to run this command to build a Docker image named "druid-hadoop-demo" with version tag "2.8.5" : 
`docker build -t druid-hadoop-demo:2.8.5 .`

but it gives me this error

> Step 14/53 : RUN curl -s https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.8.3/hadoop-2.8.3.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /usr/local/
>    ---> Running in 7baa699ccc29
>
> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
>   tar: Child returned status 1
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>   The command '/bin/sh -c curl -s https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.8.3/hadoop-2.8.3.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /usr/local/' returned a non-zero code: 2

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's a network error, indicating the file you downloaded was either corrupted in transit (it downloaded correctly for me, so unlikely to be the source), or the connection was dropped before finishing the curl command. Check for network proxies, intermittent network failures, or anything else that could interrupt the connection. You can also try to manually run curl from within a container to see if it's successful, e.g.

```
curl -o hadoop.tgz https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.8.3/hadoop-2.8.3.tar.gz
tar -tvzf hadoop.tgz
```

Comment: Druid recently released 0.17 version which fixed the issue I was having.